# JSON.stringify даёт не те данные, что нужно

Tags: javascript, json

```
var One = 1;
var Two = 2;
alert(JSON.stringify({One:Two})); // Вывод - {"One":2}
```

А надо {1:2}

**Как получить нужный формат?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы в качестве ключа было значение переменной `One` нужно использовать [Computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

```js
var One = 1;
var Two = 2;
console.log(JSON.stringify({
  [One]: Two
})); // Вывод - {"One":2}
```

Альтернативное решение - сохранить объект в переменную, добавив ему необходимые свойства и лишь затем вызвав JSON.stringify

```js
var One = 1;
var Two = 2;
var obj = {}
obj[One] = Two
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // Вывод - {"One":2}
```

Comment: Спасибо! С объектом больше подходит под поставленную задачу.

Comment: Первое IE не поддерживает, это грустно (...хотя если автор использует babel, то наверно пофиг...)

Comment: @andreymal, но в EDGE уже сделали :)